# Express.js View Engine vs. Compiling Manually

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp, handlebars.js

I'm currently using Express.js with the `hbs` library so that I can use Handlebars templates in my application. I've recently started creating a build system using `gulp` for my app and I've found packages like `gulp-handlebars`. My question is, what are the advantages/disadvantages of using an Express view engine like `hbs` over using the vanilla JS `handlebars` library and a gulp plugin like `gulp-handlebars` to compile my templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using gulp, grunt, etc and a HBS plugin can be used to compile static html files or to precompile templates to load via a javascript loader (such as require). Using the express template engine allows you to compile server side at request time for dynamic pages (like a rails or php app). You can also use Handlebars on the client side for dynamic updates, like in Ember.js. It really comes down to what sort of app you are building.

Comment: `gulp-handlebars` can be used [to _precompile_ templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-handlebars#compiling-to-separate-modules-for-nodebrowserify), that can still be used to render dynamic data.

Comment: Fair. Updated answer.

Comment: My application is not a dynamic one. It's just my personal website so I'm simply using `hbs` to help me create layouts and templates and more easily create pages. The only data that I'm inserting is things like the `<title>` tag into the layout for each page, and the contents of a blog post into the post template. Right now I'm getting the post ID based on the URL and retrieving the contents from the database and then inserting it into the handlebars post template. I'm not using any JavaScript client side as my pages are all static after they load. Not sure if there is a better approach to it.

Comment: At that scale there will be no measurable performance difference, so it is really just whatever is easier for you to develop.

Answer (score 1):

Given that Express will cache compiled templates in "production mode" (`process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`), or when the [`view cache` setting](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set) is enabled manually, having Gulp precompile templates usually does not give a lot of extra (performance) benefits.

`gulp-handlebars` is more useful if you're using Handlebars templates client-side.

Comment: See my comment to JustH in regards to what kind of an app I'm building.

Comment: @JoeSweeney I agree with the assessment that you should just use what you're comfortable with (which in my case would just be using `res.render('template', ...)`).